# Electron, Webpack, React. When using clipboard; 'fs' is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, clipboard

So I'm running electron via `export ELECTRON_START_URL=http://localhost:8080 && electron .` In a react / webpack / electron desktop app. I'm trying to read from the system clipboard upon paste key combination (ctrl + v).

So electron works, I DO NOT have a Copy & Paste shortcut enabled in my menu definitions (I don't plan on having a menu).

I'm trying to read a key combination on one component within the react app...similar to:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

import {clipboard} from 'electron';

const Thing = (props) {

  const keyboardHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 86 && e.ctrlKey) {
      let pasted = clipboard.readText();
      console.log(pasted);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', keyboardHandler);
    // Remove event listeners on cleanup
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', keyboardHandler);
    };
  }, []);
 
  return <SomeComp onKeyDown={ (e) => keyBoardHandler(e)}/>

}

export default Thing;
```

I'm getting the error:

```
external_"electron":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at eval (external_"electron":1)
    at Object.electron (bundle.js:1167)
```

EDIT: this is my main.js (electron) code:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, clipboard } = require('electron');

const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
let mainWindow;

function createWindow () {
  const startUrl = process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL || url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, '../index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true,
  });
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 700, height: 210, frame: true, transprent: true, hasShadow: true });
  mainWindow.loadURL(startUrl);
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

app.commandLine.appendSwitch("enable-transparent-visuals");
app.on('ready', createWindow);
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});
app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

Comment: I think you have disabled nodeIntegration while creating BrowserWindow.

Comment: I haven't disabled it, it seems to be enabled by default. I have updated the post to show my main.js code

Comment: Can you try enabling nodeIntegration explicitly?

Comment: I changed it to `mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 700, height: 210, frame: true, webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true} });` it still gives the same error

Comment: Change import syntax to commonjs. Try :
const { clipboard } = require("electron");

Comment: 'require' is not defined :(

Comment: Do you use a bundler?

Comment: it's webpack, babel, react, and electron

Answer (score 0):

add "window." to the require node function as following:

```
window.require('electron');
```

That works for me, hope with you too.